# Operation in a cell array

Tags: matlab

Good afternoon,

I have a cell array with a lot of multiband images (6 bands for each image). 
My multidimensional array is called 'D' and have two columns: the first one with the name of the images and the second one with the image file (with the row, band...). First of all, I want to transform it in double format (now it's uint16) with the following code, but I receive the following error "??? Error using ==> double Too many input arguments."

```
D= double(C{:,1});
```

And then, I have that values:

```
a1=1957 
a2= 1900 
a3= 1554 
a4=1036 
a5=215 
a6=80
```

And what I'm trying to do is create a loop (I'm simplifying the question) because I need to do the same operation on every band of the images. The code looked like this:

```
for k = 1:band(D{:,1})
    band1= D(:,:,1);
    band2= D(:,:,2);
    ...
    band1*a1=output1
    band2*a2=output2
end
```

But I really don't know how to express that. Really thanks in advance

---

On each line of the cell array, there's a multiband image. This is the way I've created:

```
fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));
C = cell(length(fileNames), 2);
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    filename = fileNames(k).name;
    C{k, 1} = filename;
    C{k, 2} = imread(filename);
end
```

Comment: I think you are confusing the terms cell arrays and multidimensional arrays.. Can you show a small portion of `C` (one or two rows would suffice, with whatever is stored in those cells)?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Cell array! ;)

Comment: Its not clear what is stored in the cell array, please give us an example

Comment: On each line of the cell array, there's a multiband image. This is the way I've created. fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));

C = cell(length(fileNames), 1);
C = cell(length(fileNames), 2); 
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    filename = fileNames(k).name;
    C{k} = imread(filename);
    C{k, 1} = filename; C{k, 2} = imread(filename); 
end

Comment: I included your comment in the question (with minor edits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you need like so:

```
% Put your a in an array:
a = [1957 1900 1554 1036 215 80];

fileNames = dir(fullfile(myPath, '*.tif'));
C = cell(length(fileNames), 2);
% Allocate output as well
output = cell(length(fileNames), 1);
for k = 1:length(fileNames)
    filename = fileNames(k).name;
    C{k, 1} = filename;
    imData = imread(filename);
    C{k, 2} = imData;

    % Loop over the bands and multiply
    curOutput = zeros(size(imData));
    for nBand = 1:size(imData, 3)
        curOutput(:, :, nBand) = a(nBand) * double(imData(:, :, nBand));
    end

    % Store output
    output{k} = curOutput;

    % Note: The above loop over the bands can be replaced by
    % output{k} = bsxfun(@times, double(imData), permute(a, [3 1 2]));
end
```

You could also do the same thing in a single line using the following

```
% After your loop...
Cdata = C(:, 2);

% OR:
%
% Generate some random data like yours (I think)
% Cdata = arrayfun(@(x){uint16((2 ^ 16 - 1) * rand(10, 10, 6))}, zeros(10, 1));

% Then do:
output = cellfun(@(x)bsxfun(@times, double(x), permute(a, [3 1 2])), Cdata, ...
    'UniformOutput', false)
```

This uses an anonymous function to do the conversion and multiplication that you want in one step. The `bsxfun` with the `permute` around the third argument is to apply the multiplication of vector `a` along the third dimension of each element of cell array `Cdata`. The result is a cell array the same size as `Cdata`.

Comment: Wakjah, thanks! I'm trying it but I receive the following error (but I'm trying to solve it!): ">> output = cell(length(fileNames, 1));
??? Error using ==> length
Too many input arguments."

Comment: Fixed the issue with the error you were receiving. Had a missing parenthesis.